# how to create a variable using an array?

Tags: php, variables, do-while

this is the code

```
        $get_favory = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM favory WHERE user1='$username'");

        $values = "";

        while($fav = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_favory)) {
        $user2 = $fav['user2'];
        $values = " OR added_by='".$user2."'";
        }

        echo $values;
```

the values variable must be like this : OR added_by='zac' OR added_by='john' OR added_by='emily'
but i get this result : OR added_by='zac'

what i have to do?

Comment: use .= to append to a string

Comment: Use `IN` not multiple `OR`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Why your code is not working

You're overwriting the variable every time instead of appending the new value.

### Solution

Replace

```
$values = " OR added_by='".$user2."'";
```

With

```
$values .= " OR added_by='".$user2."'";
```

### Don't use mysql_ extension

mysql_ extension is deprecated. You should use mysqli_ instead.
Your code should be:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect(host,username,password,db_name);
$get_favory = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM favory WHERE user1='$username'");

$values = "";

while($fav = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_favory)) {
$user2 = $fav['user2'];
$values .= " OR added_by='".$user2."'";
}

echo $values;
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be simpler using the `IN` clause:

```
// you only need user2
$get_favory = mysql_query("SELECT user2 FROM favory WHERE user1='$username'");

while($fav = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_favory)) {
    $user2[] = $fav['user2'];
}
$values = "'" . implode("','", $user2) . "'";
echo "SELECT * FROM table WHERE added_by IN ($values)";
```

**You should move to PDO or at a minimum the MySQLi extension.**